# Image border styling

Tags: android, css

I am creating an application where i have a list of images. On clicking the images i get a thick border around the image at some distance from the image.

I need to edit this border and reduce the space between the image and the border using CSS.

Any suggestions on how i can achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

The CSS used for this is:

```
.logo_set_iphone {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    padding-top: -50px;
    padding-bottom: -50px;
    padding-left: -50px;
    padding-right: -50px;

}
.logo_set_iphone img {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    float: center;
    margin-bottom: -6px; 
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    padding-bottom: -10px;
    padding-left: -10px;
    padding-right: -10px;
}
```

all the images are placed inside the class named "logoset"

Comment: Can you post a demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.container img{
    border:20px solid black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function change(){
this.style.borderWidth="10px"
    }
</script>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" onclick="change.call(this)" >
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" onclick="change.call(this)" >
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" onclick="change.call(this)" >
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" onclick="change.call(this)" >
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" onclick="change.call(this)" >
</div>
</html>
```

Try the updated code.. From your comment i think this is what your looking for.. onclick the border of the image changes..

Comment: dint make any difference to the border but the images stopped getting selected.

Comment: @Khush if you want to permanently add the border for the image you can use `img:visited { border: 15px solid black; }` along with `img:active`

Comment: @Khush do you want an the border to reduce only when clicked `img:active` or want the border reduce permanently on the img which has been clicked - `img:visited`??

Comment: @Vivek: It has nothing to do with the image being visited. When i select an image. a border is reflected around it. I want to edit that. When i click on another image after that, another image is selected, same behavior has to be reflected there.

Comment: @khush updated the code.. initially,a border is set -- when you click on it -- the border changes as per your needs -- done by the JS..